# How to making a plot of indicator (index)?

Tags: python, plot, graph, indicator

i have  two matrix with numver.
MatA
MatB
i like to check for any row in MatA if the number appear in the same raw of MatB.
if True, i like to plot a graph that color a square of the appropriate index
I want to make a plot looking like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJBIr.png)

Answer (score 0):

*want to make a plot looking like this: enter image description here*

This should be achievable using heatmap, you might use [seaborn.heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) for that - just feed it with 2D array (`numpy.array`) holding `0` and `1` in corresponding places.